# Why ionic 4 social sharing plugin not working in browser?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm creating ionic 4 angular app , and using ionic 4 social sharing plugin to share app.in mobile devices it's working fine but in browser it is not working.
[Here is ionic 4 social sharing documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing)

Comment: Not given proper solutions, then why peoples down voted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Ionic social sharing is native plugin so its required cordova to run. You are running  it in browser so it will not working. Try to run **ionic cordova run browser**. before running this command in cmd, Please make sure browser plateform is installed.

Comment: ionic cordova run browser----i'm tried this command but not working.

Comment: Error: exec proxy not found for :: SocialSharing :: shareViaWhatsApp.

Comment: Ok. This plugin will only work in mobile device not on browser. You can refer https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/973

Comment: Property 'plugins' does not exist on type 'Window' error occured.